# How Can I fix the following Error in leetcode?

Tags: algorithm

For the question:
Given an array of integers nums, return the number of good pairs.

A pair (i, j) is called good if nums[i] == nums[j] and i < j.

I wrote the following code:

```
 int numIdenticalPairs(vector<int>& nums) {
   
 int count[102];

for (int num : nums) {
  count[num]++;
}

int totalCount = 0;

// Calculate total number of pairs possible
for (int i : count) {
  totalCount += ((i) * (i-1))/2;
}

return totalCount;
```

}

I am getting following error help me fix it:

> Line 21: Char 26: runtime error: signed integer overflow: -1844207608 * -1844207609 cannot be represented in type 'int' (solution.cpp)
> SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior prog_joined.cpp:30:26

Comment: clearly the error tells integer overflow. read the error carefully.

Comment: Your question title should be more specific and straight to the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type of question, you need to give the constraints as well. Still, I'm trying from my experience.

In C++, the array you declare in the function/method without malloc or new, goes to in stack and keeps garbage values if you don't put anything. So, you need to initialize it first. Do this:

```
memset(count, 0, sizeof(count));
```

As I am not seeing any constraints here, if values of count[] is even near **10^5**, you will get integer overflow in multiplication of **i x (i-1)** as well. So try this:

```
for (int i : count) {
    totalCount += ((i) * ((long long)(i-1)))/2;
}
```

Hope, these will solve the problem.

**Edit:** Now I use Java for problem-solving. So there might be some error in syntax.